Accidentally installed Linux on a NFTS partition. How can I get back Windows?
I have just bought a new Lenovo Ideapad slim 5i laptop, 1tb ssd. I've just installed linux but when handling with partition there was a 900tb nfts partition and i used part of it to install linux. Right now Ubuntu works but I don't manage to use windows. On the grub menu if I select windows I see automatical repair but then it fails to repair.
Anyone could help me to restore windows?
Right now on the disk utility app I have the following situation:

273 MB — 218 MB free (20.0% full), FAT (32-bit version) — Mounted at /boot/efi, /dev/nvme0n1p1, EFI System
273 MB, /dev/nvme0n1p2, Microsoft Reserved
350 GB — 316 GB free (9.7% full), Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root, /dev/nvme0n1p3, Linux Filesystem
-672 GB, Unallocated Space, /dev/nvme0n1
-2.1 GB, NTFS — Not Mounted, /dev/nvme0n1p4, Microsoft Windows Recovery Environment (System, No Automount)

Before installing Linux the 350GB and 672 partitions were only one NFTS partition.
I would be very grateful if you can help me!!
After the testdisk analysis I got the following result:
Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 1024 GB / 953 GiB - CHS 976762 64 32
 Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
P EFI System                  2048     534527     532480 [EFI System Partition]
P Linux filesys. data       567296  684163071  683595776
D MS Data                684163072 1996312575 1312149504 [Windows]
D MS Data               1992216577 1996312576    4096000
>D MS Data               1996312576 2000408575    4096000 [WINRE_DRV]


Then proceeding on MS Data [WINRE_DRV] with deepsearch I obtain the following result:
Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 1024 GB / 953 GiB - CHS 976762 64 32
 Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>D EFI System                  2048     534527     532480 [EFI System Partition] [SYSTEM_DRV]
D MS Data                     2054     534533     532480 [SYSTEM_DRV]
D MS Data                    72763      78936       6174
D MS Data                    78936      85109       6174 [Boot]

